# Check for Blank Text Boxes

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a series of text boxes on a page, with common names `Number` and `Scale`:

```
<input type="text" name="Number">
<input type="text" name="Scale">
```

I also have my submit button:

```
<input type="SUBMIT" value="Process Now">
```

I am using jQuery on my webpage too - is there code that will check all instances of `Number` and `Scale` and not allow the user to submit until all the text `Number` and `Scale` text boxes have an entry in them?

Comment: What heve you tried? Your question _is there code that will check all instances of Number and Scale_ answer is __Yes__

Comment: [Yes, there is code that will check that](https://www.google.com/#q=jquery+form+validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var emptytxt= $('[name=Number],[name=Scale]').filter(function () {
  return $.trim($(this).val()) == '';
});
if (emptytxt.length) { /* Error. has one or more empty txtboxes with name Number,Scale */ }
```

Comment: Do I need to wrap this in anything... or can the jQuery start with `var`?

Comment: on click of submit button.

Comment: I have a jsFiddle of this - http://jsfiddle.net/p3VdE/ - any suggestions as to what the problem might be please?

Comment: @DustinCook: check this http://jsfiddle.net/p3VdE/1/